# URL Encoding - 3 Symbols for 1 character

Tags: http, urlencode

For the following url,

```
www.some-website.com/this’-and-that
```

the `’` character, expands to `%E2%80%99`

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Because that's the Unicode curved (smart) quote character `’`, not an apostrophe `'`.

That character is `U+2019` in the table on [Quotation marks in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs#Quotation_marks_in_Unicode).

Since URLs can only contain ASCII characters according to [RFC 1738 - Uniform Resource Locators](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html), that character is being percent encoded.

Reference: [URL Encoding (or: 'What are those "%20" codes in URLs?')](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)

Comment: hmm. I try putting that quote ’ in a tex to hex-16 editor, and i get 0x92. anyways, thanks for the info. is there a guide somewhere that would tell me how the we arrive at %E2%80%99 ?

Comment: a) The explanation is correct, but the current URI spec is RFC 3986.

b) The expansion to three bytes is due to UTF-8 encoding.